# ZF2 Routing regexp

Tags: regex, zend-framework, routes, zend-framework2

I try to validate a route in zend framework 2.

Example:

- valid - /foo/overview/1-2015
- valid - /foo/overview/9999-2015
- invalid /foo/overview/sd-2015
- invalid - /foo/overview/10001-2015

I tried this code, but I received 404 error:

```
'overview' => array(
    'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => array(
    'route'    => '/foo/overview/:nr',
    'constraints' => array('nr' => '^[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{4}$',),
    'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Foo\Controller\Foo',
    'action'     => 'overview',
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
```

thanks

Comment: Try using `\b[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{4}$`, it will match the last hyphenated numbers.

Comment: whay u use [0-9]? u relay need zero in result ? better [1-9]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is enough to use `[0-9]{1,4}-[0-9]{4}` for your constraint value, since the starting `^` and the closing `$` are automatically added by the framework (check the `match` function in the `Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment` class).

Comment: Thanks so much! Regards

Comment: @Beppe if the answer is correct, don't forget to check it as the accepted one!